# Google Apps Scripts IF OR statement

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am validating a number of cells based on cell color. If a cell color is white then it will return false, otherwise return true. However, I can't seem to figure out the OR statement. I am trying to have the code check if B6 OR D6 OR F6 OR B12 OR D12 OR F12 OR B18 OR D18 OR F18 OR B24 OR D24 OR F24 background == '#ffffff' == true) {return false;}.
When I save the record, I only want those cell values that are TRUE to be saved in the database and ignored the cell values that are false. I am not really good with Google Scripts App so any help would be appreciated.

```
function validate(){

    var myGoogleSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var shUserForm = myGoogleSheet.getSheetByName("UserForm");
    //var ui=SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); // to create the instance of the user interface to show the alert
    
    if (shUserForm.getRange("B6").getBackground()=='#ffffff' == true){
    return false;
    }
    
    if (shUserForm.getRange("D6").getBackground()=='#ffffff' == true){
    return false;
    }
    
    if (shUserForm.getRange("F6").getBackground()=='#ffffff' == true){
    return false;
    }

    if (shUserForm.getRange("B12").getBackground()=='#ffffff' == true){
    return false;
    }

    if (shUserForm.getRange("D12").getBackground()=='#ffffff' == true){
    return false;
    }

    if (shUserForm.getRange("F12").getBackground()=='#ffffff' == true){
    return false;
    }

    if (shUserForm.getRange("B18").getBackground()=='#ffffff' == true){
    return false;
    }

    if (shUserForm.getRange("D18").getBackground()=='#ffffff' == true){
    return false;
    }

    if (shUserForm.getRange("F18").getBackground()=='#ffffff' == true){
    return false;
    }

    if (shUserForm.getRange("B24").getBackground()=='#ffffff' == true){
    return false;
    }

    if (shUserForm.getRange("D24").getBackground()=='#ffffff' == true){
    return false;
    }

    if (shUserForm.getRange("F24").getBackground()=='#ffffff' == true){
    return false;
    }
    
  return true;

   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question, I understood as follows.

- You want to return `true` when the background color of one of the cells "B6", "D6", "F6", "B12", "D12", "F12", "B18", "D18", "F18", "B24", "D24", "F24" is `#ffffff`. Even when the color except for `#ffffff` is included, you want to return `false`.
- From `When I save the record, I only want those cell values that are TRUE to be saved in the database and ignored the cell values that are false.`, you want to retrieve values from "B6", "D6", "F6", "B12", "D12", "F12", "B18", "D18", "F18", "B24", "D24", "F24" when the background color is `#ffffff`.

### Answer for question 1:

When your script is modified, how about the following modification?

#### Modification points:

In the case of `shUserForm.getRange("B6").getBackground() == '#ffffff' == true`, it is required to be modified as follows.

```
    if (shUserForm.getRange("B6").getBackground() == '#ffffff') {
      return true;
    }
```

When this is reflected in your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script 1:

In this modification, your script was modified.

```js
function validate() {
  var myGoogleSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var shUserForm = myGoogleSheet.getSheetByName("UserForm");
  if (shUserForm.getRange("B6").getBackground() == '#ffffff') {
    return true;
  }
  if (shUserForm.getRange("D6").getBackground() == '#ffffff') {
    return true;
  }
  if (shUserForm.getRange("F6").getBackground() == '#ffffff') {
    return true;
  }
  if (shUserForm.getRange("B12").getBackground() == '#ffffff') {
    return true;
  }
  if (shUserForm.getRange("D12").getBackground() == '#ffffff') {
    return true;
  }
  if (shUserForm.getRange("F12").getBackground() == '#ffffff') {
    return true;
  }
  if (shUserForm.getRange("B18").getBackground() == '#ffffff') {
    return true;
  }
  if (shUserForm.getRange("D18").getBackground() == '#ffffff') {
    return true;
  }
  if (shUserForm.getRange("F18").getBackground() == '#ffffff') {
    return true;
  }
  if (shUserForm.getRange("B24").getBackground() == '#ffffff') {
    return true;
  }
  if (shUserForm.getRange("D24").getBackground() == '#ffffff') {
    return true;
  }
  if (shUserForm.getRange("F24").getBackground() == '#ffffff') {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

#### Modified script 2:

As another approach, how about the following modification?

```js
function validate() {
  var myGoogleSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var shUserForm = myGoogleSheet.getSheetByName("UserForm");
  var v = shUserForm.getRange("B6:F24").getBackgroundObjects();
  var res = false;
  for (var r = 0; r < v.length; r += 6) {
    var [b, , d, , f] = v[r].map(e => e.asRgbColor().asHexString());
    res = [b, d, f].some(e => e.includes("#ffffff"));
    if (res) break;
  }
  return res;
}
```

- This sample is the same result as the above-modified script.

### Answer for question 2:

When you want to retrieve values from "B6", "D6", "F6", "B12", "D12", "F12", "B18", "D18", "F18", "B24", "D24", "F24" when the background color is `#ffffff`, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
function validate() {
  var myGoogleSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var shUserForm = myGoogleSheet.getSheetByName("UserForm");
  var range = shUserForm.getRange("B6:F24");
  var values = range.getValues();
  var backgrounds = range.getBackgroundObjects();
  var temp = [];
  for (var r = 0; r < values.length; r += 6) {
    var [vb, , vd, , vf] = values[r];
    var [bb, , bd, , bf] = backgrounds[r].map(e => e.asRgbColor().asHexString());
    temp.push([bb, bd, bf].map((e, i) => e.includes("#ffffff") ? [vb, vd, vf][i] : ""));
  }
  var res = temp.flat().filter(String);
  console.log(res); // You can check the retrieved values.
  return res;
}
```

- When this script is run, about the cells "B6", "D6", "F6", "B12", "D12", "F12", "B18", "D18", "F18", "B24", "D24", "F24", the cell values are retrieved when the background color is `#ffffff`.
- Unfortunately, I cannot understand your expected value from `When I save the record, I only want those cell values that are TRUE to be saved in the database and ignored the cell values that are false.`. So, when this returned value is not your expected value, please provide the sample value. By this, I would like to modify it.

### References:

- [if...else](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else)
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

Comment: Tanaike - I really appreciate your response and other options. I apologize for not being clear and will add the submit to database code to help understand my end goal. I only want to save the cell value when the cell color is not (#ffffff) white. Since the background cell colors are (green, yellow, blue and red). For example, if a user clicks on B6, D6, F6 the cell color will turn green and it will save all three cell values. However, if the user selects B6 then I only want to save the value in B6 since it will = true. I hope it helps.

Comment: @Roe Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill. From your reply, it seems that your posted question is different from your reply. But, I would like to support you. But, unfortunately, I cannot understand your actual expected result from your reply. Can I ask you about the detail of your actual expected result? By correctly understanding your actual expected result, I would like to think of a solution. If you can cooperate to resolve your actual question, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: @TanaikeThank you very much for your response. My request is the same but I may have worded it a little differently in my response. I added an image to show you an example of the user options (B6 or D6 or F6) they can select. I am trying to figure out the OR statement since a user may select 1, 2 or 3 of the emojis. How or where would the OR statement be inserted since all cells need to == true for the record to be saved. 
if (shUserForm.getRange("B6").getBackground() == '#ffffff') {
    return true;
  }
  if (shUserForm.getRange("D6").getBackground() == '#ffffff') {
    return true;
  }

Comment: @Roe Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill again. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your actual expected question from your reply. About `My request is the same`, unfortunately, I cannot understand this. Because I cannot still understand your actual expected question from your reply. I apologize for this again.

Comment: @Roe About your reply, where can I see your image of `I added an image to show you an example of the user options (B6 or D6 or F6) they can select.`? About `I am trying to figure out the OR statement since a user may select 1, 2 or 3 of the emojis.`, what are `1, 2 or 3 of the emojis`? In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? If you can cooperate to resolve your actual question, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: I am not sure what happened to the image. However, I am working with your code so I will mark this answered since your Modified script #1 helped with replacing my original code. I will submit a separate request about saving data into the database. Thank you again for all your help.

Comment: @Roe Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your other question, when I saw your new question, I would like to understand it and think of a solution.